# Combine just values of list of python dictionaries into single dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I'm working on a python AWS Cognito implementation using boto3. `jwt.decode` on the IdToken yields a payload that's in the form of a dictionary, like so:

```py
{
    "sub": "a uuid",
    "email_verified": True,
    "iss": "https://cognito-idp....",
    "phone_number_verified": False,
    "cognito:username": "19407ea0-a79d-11e6-9ce4-09487ca06884",
    "given_name": "Aron Filbert",
    "aud": "my client app",
    "token_use": "id",
    "auth_time": 1480547504,
    "nickname": "Aron Filbert",
    "phone_number": "+14025555555",
    "exp": 1480551104,
    "iat": 1480547504,
    "email": "my@email.com"
}
```

So I designed a User class that consumes that dictionary. Works great, until I need to hit Cognito again and grab fresh user details to make sure nothing changed (say, from another device). My return payload from the `get_user()` call ends up looking like a list of dictionaries:

```py
[
    {
        "Name": "sub",
        "Value": "a uuid"
    },
    {
        "Name": "email_verified",
        "Value": "true"
    },        
    {
        "Name": "phone_number_verified",
        "Value": "false"
    },
    {
        "Name": "phone_number",
        "Value": "+114025555555"
    },
    {
        "Name": "given_name",
        "Value": "Aron Filbert"
    },
    {
        "Name": "email",
        "Value": "my@email.com"
    }        
]
```

Since I might be hitting that `get_user()` Cognito endpoint a lot, I'm looking for an efficient way to grab JUST the values of each dictionary in the list and use them to form the keys:values of a new dictionary. Example:

```py
{
    "sub": "a uuid",  # From first list item
    "email_verified": True,  # From next list item        
    ...
}
```

Being new to Python, I'm struggling with how to accomplish this elegantly and efficiently.

Comment: First you should do it simply and inefficiently, then worry about improvements (that's how you learn). Have you tried something straightforward/brute force?

Comment: Totally agree. The reason I'm asking is because I'm on a bit of a deadline using a back end that I'm not familiar with. I've written a quick iterator to accomplish my task, and considered using `any()` as well, but was hoping for a more pythonic solution

Comment: `{k["Name"]:k["Value"] for k in list_of_dicts_from_get_user}`?

Comment: But you will have to turn the stringy bools into actual bools etc; that's a different question (but could be done in the same dict comprehension of course).

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: No worries:) As your question doesn't have any votes nor answers, you should consider deleting it if you don't think it will help future readers. Otherwise feel free to add an answer of your own.

Comment: If you could illuminate in an answer how to yield the right types out of the dict comprehension that you posted, I'd upvote you and accept your answer. It was almost exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: In case you just need to convert only the bools, I added an answer. Other cases should be similarly straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, the bulk of your work can be done by a dict comprehension:

```
lst = get_user() # or something similar, lst is a list of dicts
parsed_res = {k["Name"]:k["Value"] for k in lst}
```

This only differs from your expected output in that it contains `'true'` and `'false'` whereas you want bools in your final result. Well, the simplest solution is to define a function that does this conversion for you:

```
def boolify(inp):
    if inp=='true':
        return True
    elif inp=='false':
        return False
    else:
        return inp

parsed_res = {k["Name"]:boolify(k["Value"]) for k in lst}
```

The same thing *could* be done in the comprehension itself, but it wouldn't be any clearer, nor efficient. This way you can do additional manipulations in your keys if you later realize that there are other stuff you want to do with your payload before storing.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary comprehension, as Andras answered above, is a simple, Pythonic one-liner for your case. Some style guidelines ([such as Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=List_Comprehensions#List_Comprehensions)), however, recommend against them if they introduce complex logic or take up more than two or three lines:

> Okay to use for simple cases. Each portion must fit on one line:
>   mapping expression, for clause, filter expression. Multiple for
>   clauses or filter expressions are not permitted. Use loops instead
>   when things get more complicated.
>
> **Yes:**
>
> ```py
> result = []
> for x in range(10):
>     for y in range(5):
>         if x * y > 10:
>             result.append((x, y))
>
> for x in xrange(5):
>     for y in xrange(5):
>         if x != y:
>             for z in xrange(5):
>                 if y != z:
>                     yield (x, y, z)
>
> return ((x, complicated_transform(x))
>         for x in long_generator_function(parameter)
>         if x is not None)
>
> squares = [x * x for x in range(10)]
>
> eat(jelly_bean for jelly_bean in jelly_beans
>     if jelly_bean.color == 'black')
> ```
>
> **No:**
>
> ```py
> result = [(x, y) for x in range(10) for y in range(5) if x * y > 10]
>
> return ((x, y, z)
>         for x in xrange(5)
>         for y in xrange(5)
>         if x != y
>         for z in xrange(5)
>         if y != z)
> ```

Dictionary comprehension is perfectly appropriate in your instance, but for the sake of completeness, this is a general method for performing operations with a couple of for-loops if you decide to do anything fancier:

```py
for <dict> in <list>:
    for <key>, <value> in <dict>:
        # Perform any applicable operations.
        <new_dict>[<key>] = <value>
```

which comes out to...

```py
user = get_user()
user_info = {}

for info in user:
    for name, value in info:
        n, v = info[name], info[value]
        if v.lowercase() == 'true':
            v = True
        else if v.lowercase() == 'false':
            v = False
        user_info[n] = v
```